# USB Vendor ID for GIGABYTE

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-debug, adb

I start development with Ubuntu and I need to add a [udev rules file that contains a USB configuration.](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) 
I do not find Gigabyte in [this table](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds).
(model [GSmart Maya M1 v2](http://www.gigabytecm.com/en/goodscontent.php?id=12))

How to get out of this situation?

**Edit:** [I find it.](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/usb_vendors.c)

**Solution:** 0414

For other manufacturer: in terminal

~$ lsusb

and in the list something like Bus XXX Device XXX: ID **usb-vendor-id**:XXXX manufacturer

Comment: A useful resource to find usb vendor ids when you do not have the hardware. [www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)

Comment: Please post your solution (which is a good one) as an answer so that you can eventually accept it and the question will show as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

[I find it.](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/usb_vendors.c)

Solution: 0414

For other manufacturer: in terminal

~$ lsusb

and in the list something like Bus XXX Device XXX: ID usb-vendor-id:XXXX manufacturer

[useful resource to find usb vendor ids when you do not have the hardware.](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)